# Lookahead and Lookbehind validation for each letters in a string (Regular Expression XYX or XXX matching)

Tags: javascript, python, regex

I need to find the letters which have the same letter before and after. Using regular expression how do that?

Example:

```
Input                                                      ➵   Output
oooh my god                                                ➵    ooo
Llanfairpwllgwyngyllgogerychwyrndrobwllllantysiliogogogoch ➵    gog, lll, lll, ogo, gog, ogo, gog, ogo
Jewnited Snakes of Amerikkka                               ➵    kkk
skilllessness                                              ➵    lll
salpingooophoritis                                         ➵    ooo, iti
princessship / mistressship                                ➵    ssss, sss
same letter / triple letters                               ➵    ele
```

Basically, I need to find out pattern XXX or XYX, excluding special characters or space.

Comment: [a-zA-Z]{2,} is your search term - you want only letters and at least they have to repeat twice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution using JavaScript with regex:

```
(?=((\w)\w\2))
```

The results are stored in group 1.

```js
const inputs = [
  'oooh my god',
  'Llanfairpwllgwyngyllgogerychwyrndrobwllllantysiliogogogoch',
  'Jewnited Snakes of Amerikkka',
  'skilllessness',
  'salpingooophoritis',
  'princessship / mistressship',
  'same letter / triple letters'
];
  
const results = inputs.map(input => [...input.matchAll(/(?=((\w)\w\2))/g)].map(res => res[1]));
  
console.log(results);
```

Not sure where does `ele` come from `same letter / triple letters` and `ssss` from `princessship / mistressship`. I assume those are typos

Comment: wow, it's great.
Should we validate the palindrome sting using this method?

Comment: Sadly regex in JavaScript doesn’t support recursion so we can’t achieve it using only regex for palindromes with indefinite length. But it is possible in other flavors [that supports recursions such as PCRE](https://regex101.com/r/AIBMnW/1)

Answer (score 2):

You tagged python, thus maybe use finditer on the following pattern:

```
(?i)(?=([a-z])[a-z]\1)
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/0x9P9x/1)

---

- `(?i)` - Case-insensitive matching;
- `(?=` - Open positive lookahead;

  - `([a-z])` - Capture any letter in 1st group;
  - `[a-z]\1)` - `Match any letter followed by a backreference to the 1st group and close the lookahead.

---

```
import re

s = 'Llanfairpwllgwyngyllgogerychwyrndrobwllllantysiliogogogoch'
l = [s[m.start():m.start()+3] for m in re.finditer(r'(?i)(?=([a-z])[a-z]\1)', s)]

print(l)
```

Prints:

```
['gog', 'lll', 'lll', 'ili', 'ogo', 'gog', 'ogo', 'gog', 'ogo']
```

Comment: thanks. It's another way to resolve this.